# iptables. Маршрутизация между 2-я vpn интерфейсами

Tags: linux, iptables, openvpn, route

Есть 2-а впн интерфейса на сервере linux. tun0 - впн сервер, tun1 - клиент до другого сервера.

```
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a576:2be6:b2bd:7a71/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 12000 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.10.100.130 peer 10.10.100.129/32 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5c2e:403d:4095:47f0/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Какой маршрут нужно прописать чтобы можно было с интерфейса tun0 попасть к tun1, например, ping -I tun0 10.10.100.130

Или через forward можно было сделать?

Comment: Тут через iroute надо

Comment: Да, через iroute все получилось.